# Output values which not exists in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables driver and driver_photo. In driver_photo we are writing driver_id and his photos.
I need to make a list of drivers which are not present in driver_photo.
So the output should be like this:

```
Callsign | Name
324      | Some_Driver_Name
571      | Some_Driver_Name
```

I've tried this

```
SELECT driver.callsign, driver.name 
from driver_photo 
  JOIN driver ON driver_photo.driver_id = driver.id 
where driver.id in (select id 
                    from driver 
                    where driver_ds_account_id = 16) 
and driver.id is null;
```

But the output is nothing.

Conditions for the query are `driver_id` in `driver_photo` = `driver.id` from `driver`
`driver_ds_account_id` in `driver` = `16`

If `driver.id` is not present in `driver_photo` need to write his `callsign` and `name` in output else skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a NOT EXISTS for that:

```
select d.*
from driver d
where not exists (select *
                  from driver_photo dp
                  where dp.driver_id = d.id)
  and d.driver_ds_account_id = 16;
```